# How to convert a list of Array Values into a Map in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hi I have a payload coming in this format . Trying to write dataweave function to transform this pay load ,but i am not able to meet the exact expectation .

```
{
"OUT_ORDER_CONTENTS_TAB": [
    [
        776665544,
        100,
        "Limited C/O",
        "loanPurpose"
    ],
    [
        776665544,
         100,
        "THE PURPOSE OF PURCHASE ",
        "loanPurpose"
    ],
    [
        776665544,
         100,
        "contains blank space",
        "borrower/2/borrowerPhone"
    ]
]
}
```

Expected output format is

```
{
"/loanPurpose": ["Limited C/O","THE PURPOSE OF PURCHASE "],
"/borrower/2/borrowerPhone": ["contains blank space"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit more complex than just converting an array to a map, because inside the elements of the arrays are array and you need to group by one of the indexes (4th element) and collect the values from another (3th element).

It can be done with groupBy() and mapObject():

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload.OUT_ORDER_CONTENTS_TAB 
    groupBy ((item, index) -> item[3] ) )
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> ("/"++(key)):value map $[2])
```

Comment: Thanks , It works , Agree it will difficult for a rookie like me . Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Salim Khan for adding the slash I missed.